# A collection that represents a concatenation of two collections in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Is there a class that represents the concatenation of a collection with another collection? This class should be a Collection in itself, and should delegate all methods to the underlying (inner) collections - no extra memory should be allocated, nor any of the original collections modified.

Example usage:

```
Collection<String> foo = ...
Collection<String> bar = ...

// this should be O(1) memory and time
Collection<String> combined = concat(foo, bar);

if (combined.contains("Zee"))
  ...

for (String str : combined)
  System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: You mean something like what Python's itertools provides?

Comment: it's not really clear if you want a class that represents a collection and an item, two collections or what..

Comment: A class that represents the concatenation of two collections.

Comment: What would happen if `add()` were called on the concatentated collection? How about `remove()`?

Comment: You may want to put clarifications in your question, to help others. But, you have the English dictionary, with definitions, and the German dictionary, with definitions, and you want them in the same collection, but you want to be able to access all three collections, so the first two were not modified, and you don't want any extra memory used in this new, third collection?  Is this a correct scenario?

Comment: Better post some code snippet wherein you have the *input* ready and please tell what kind of *output* you're expecting. In any case. This will greatly improve the understanding.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the bad grammar - I should make it a habit to _read_ my questions before posting :)

Comment: OK, that's clear. Make use of `Collection#addAll()`.

Comment: That modifies the original collection - I'm looking for a solution that doesn't modify them.

Comment: For the purpose of discussion, throw NotImplemented on add (or add to the second collection). Remove should is "return first.remove() || second.remove();"

Answer (score 9):

As always for any collections stuff, look at [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). If you have `Set`s, specifically (not just a general collection), you want:

```
Set<String> combined = Sets.union(foo, bar);
```

which creates an unmodifiable view of the two sets. That is, changes in `foo` or `bar` will be reflected in `combined` (but `combined.add()` etc is not supported).

For the more generic case, you have `Iterables.concat()` but that merely lets you iterate over the joined item, the `Iterable` interface obviously doesn't include `contains` so you're a little hosed there.

The other collections utilities classes in google-collections (`com.google.common.collect.Lists` and `com.google.common.collect.Collections2`) don't contain any concatenation methods. Don't see why they couldn't, but at the moment they don't.

Comment: We found that 99% of the time, users really just needed to iterate. Hence Iterables.concat().  Internally we have a Lists.concat() as well but hardlly anyone uses it, and most of those who do could have just used the other one anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very vague. Especially *"with another item another collection"* is quite unclear.

You can at least add the contents of another `Collection` to the current `Collection` using [`Collection#addAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Here `Collection` can be anything of its subinterfaces/implementations, e.g. `List` or `Set`.

Example:

```
List<String> foos = Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3");
List<String> bars = Arrays.asList("bar1", "bar2", "bar3");
foos.addAll(bars); // Now foos contains everything.
```

**Edit**: Or do you actually want to create a *new* `Collection` based on an existing `Collection` and then add a new item to it? In this case just construct a new `Collection` with the existing `Collection` as constructor argument. E.g.:

```
List<String> foos = Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3");
List<String> bars = new ArrayList<String>(foos);
bars.add("bar"); // Now bars contains everything.
```

Comment: I always prefer native Java libraries ways to do things before going for a third-party library.

Answer (score 3):

There is not, but writing it yourself should be straight forward

```
package ch.akuhn.util;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Concat {

    public static <T> Iterable<T> all(final Iterable<T>... iterables) {
        return new Iterable<T>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<T>() {
                    Iterator<Iterable<T>> more = Arrays.asList(iterables).iterator();
                    Iterator<T> current = more.hasNext() ? more.next().iterator() : null;
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        if (current == null) return false;
                        if (current.hasNext()) return true;
                        current = more.hasNext() ? more.next().iterator() : null;
                        return this.hasNext();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public T next() {
                        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                        return current.next();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void remove() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And then

```
for (Object each: Concat.all(collection,whatever,etcetera,...)) {
    // ...
}
```

Just wrote this code here, compile at your own risk!

PS, *if you gonna write unit tests for this class, send 'em to me.*

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking for is a Java construct that allows you to put collections together without modifying the original collections.  In other words, you have collections A and B, both of size N and M respectively.  After the concat call, you still have collections A and B and their sizes are still N and M, however you have collection C as well which points to A and B, making its size N+M.

The answer is no, Java doesn't have anything out of the box that does this...  However you could write a quick wrapper that wraps a series of collections and add those collections to it.  (All it would do is maintain references to each of the collections) and you could expose get/insert methods as needed.

Comment: That is indeed what I am looking for ... was wondering if there is such a library.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) also has a more general [CompositeCollection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/collection/CompositeCollection.html) class which can be used as an interface to an arbitrary number of `Collection`s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking.  My interpretation of your question is that your looking for the add method on the Collection.  I don't think that's what you're asking though.

Comment: I'm looking for a collection that encapsulates the concatenation of two collections, _without_ allocating a significant amount of memory or modifying the original collections.

Answer (score 0):

Try [InterleavingEnumeration](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/classes/collections/collections.InterleavingEnumeration.html) or apache's commons collections' [ListUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#union%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) (ListUtils.union())